# Extract access token from JSON

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm receiving some authentication details via an API and they are being returned as JSON. I am trying to extract the "access token" part to be used in another request.

The result of my cURL request is:

```
{"token_type":"bearer","access_token":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMVfbQAAAAAAK7qYRQOgdZ771TrJ6pZ7nugCwVQ%3DLKcongtwy3lcBDbPSEreC9DfhJk3Gm7qyQInqhFAxYvo1clv4S"}
```

I'm trying to get just the access token from this:

```
json_decode($result, true);
$token = $response['access_token'];
var_dump($token);
```

But the result is always `NULL`

I have also tried to convert the JSON to a string so I can extract it using some sort of regex but cannot get it to return anything except `NULL`

Comment: $response = json_decode($result,true);

Comment: Are you storing json_decode somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't assigned `$response` to the return value of `json_decode()`:

```
$response = json_decode($result, true);
$token = $response['access_token'];
var_dump($token);
```

Online [demo here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/9qVO2R).

Comment: I've just tried this but am still getting NULL even though I can echo out the JSON and clearly see "access token" there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$obj=json_decode($result);
echo $obj->access_token;
```

**OR**

```
$array=json_decode($result,true);
echo $array['access_token'];
```